# Use systemd to start ppp on a VLAN on boot

Tags: systemd, vlan, pppoe, pppd

I'm replacing my consumer router/AP with a linux box. My consumer router dialed in to my ISP via a PPPoE link on a tagged VLAN. I have a working setup configured where `ppp` uses the tagged device `enp7s0.201` and it runs fine until I reboot. When rebooting, `ppp` comes up before the VLAN device is created and it immediately dies.

```
[me@router ~]$ sudo journalctl -b | egrep 'ppp|enp7s0'
Feb 11 03:01:22 router kernel: r8169 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: renamed from eth0
Feb 11 03:01:23 router systemd[1]: ppp@centurylink.service: Unit is bound to inactive unit sys-subsystem-net-devices-enp7s0.201.device. Stopping, too.
Feb 11 03:01:23 router systemd-networkd[444]: /etc/systemd/network/enp7s0.201.netdev:5: Unknown section 'VLAN'. Ignoring.
Feb 11 03:01:25 router systemd-networkd[444]: enp7s0.201: netdev ready
Feb 11 03:01:25 router systemd-networkd[444]: enp7s0: IPv6 successfully enabled
Feb 11 03:01:25 router kernel: r8169 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: link down
Feb 11 03:01:25 router kernel: r8169 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: link down
Feb 11 03:01:25 router kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp7s0: link is not ready
Feb 11 03:01:25 router systemd-networkd[444]: enp7s0.201: IPv6 successfully enabled
Feb 11 03:01:25 router systemd-networkd[444]: enp7s0: Gained carrier
Feb 11 03:01:25 router systemd-networkd[444]: enp7s0.201: Gained carrier
Feb 11 03:01:25 router systemd-networkd[444]: enp7s0.201: Lost carrier
Feb 11 03:01:26 router systemd-networkd[444]: enp7s0: Lost carrier
Feb 11 03:01:27 router systemd-networkd[444]: enp7s0.201: Gained IPv6LL
Feb 11 03:01:27 router systemd-networkd[444]: enp7s0: Gained carrier
Feb 11 03:01:27 router kernel: r8169 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: link up
Feb 11 03:01:27 router kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp7s0: link becomes ready
Feb 11 03:01:27 router systemd-networkd[444]: enp7s0.201: Gained carrier
Feb 11 03:01:29 router systemd-networkd[444]: enp7s0: Gained IPv6LL
Feb 11 03:01:32 router systemd-networkd[444]: enp7s0: Lost carrier
Feb 11 03:01:32 router kernel: r8169 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: link down
Feb 11 03:01:32 router systemd-networkd[444]: enp7s0.201: Lost carrier
Feb 11 03:01:35 router systemd-networkd[444]: enp7s0: Gained carrier
Feb 11 03:01:35 router kernel: r8169 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: link up
Feb 11 03:01:35 router systemd-networkd[444]: enp7s0.201: Gained carrier
```

I've removed a `Before=network.target` from the `ppp@.service` file and instead added a drop-in `BindsTo=sys-subsystem-net-devices-enp7s0.201.device`.

```
[me@router ~]$ sudo systemctl cat ppp@centurylink
[sudo] password for me: 
# /usr/lib/systemd/system/ppp@.service
[Unit]
Description=PPP link to %I
#Before=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/pppd call %I nodetach nolog

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

# /etc/systemd/system/ppp@centurylink.service.d/port-bind.conf
[Unit]
BindsTo=sys-subsystem-net-devices-enp7s0.201.device
```

However looking at where `pppd` runs during boot, it's still well before when `enp7s0.201` is available.

---

**EDIT: I'm an idiot.** I forgot that I also needed an `After=sys-subsystem-net-devices-enp7s0.201.device` in the drop-in as well.